# Listen and notify using task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have such class for looping listening something and notify subscribers about some event.

Is this class right or there is another better realization of this,using TPL?

```
public class Listener
{
    public event EventHandler EventRaised;
    private void RaiseEvent()
    {
       if(EventRaised!=null)EventRaised(someParam);
    }
    public Task Listen()
    {
       return Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            while(true)
            {
               //listen for some event
               RaiseEvent();
            }
        }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

Example

```
var listener = new Listener();
listener.EventRaised += SomeMethod;
listerner.Listen();
```

I asked about best way of notifying subscribers about some event in background.

Comment: What is your goal here?  This class doesn't make sense...

Comment: See topic, i have edited it.

Comment: This class will just "notify" the subscriber continually, in a neverending loop, and eat CPU up... What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Could you give an example of an event, you want to listen to? Is it actually an event raised by another class or do you need to poll an external resource?

Comment: In code before RaiseEvent() must be some action(see comment in code).

Comment: This code is just example, I want to know how to notify subscribers in best way using TPL.

Comment: Notify subscribers from neverending loop!

Comment: It,i.e., listen port , get some from this port and raise event. If some data from port retrieved - event raise and notify subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely one way of doing it, but you could also use the Rx library. I would recommend not having a while inside of your Task because tasks are meant to terminate. At some point, whether from exceptions or errors. Using the Task.ContinueWith method might be a better alternative.

Comment: And how I can make neverending loop whithout 'while'? I need to listen in all time during programm work.

Comment: Make a ContinueWith over loaded with that task for a recursive call aswell as other methods for error checking and exception handling.

Comment: @IEnumerable This other question has an answer that shows this quite nicely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654632/how-do-i-write-a-scalable-socket-server-using-c-sharp-4-0